# rack-google-analytics

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rack

I'm using the gem rack-google-analytics in my rails project but when I run it in production mode I get an error.

rack-google-analytics-0.11.0/lib/rack/google-analytics.rb:11:in `initialize': Tracker must be set! (ArgumentError)

I'm trying to find out what this means. initialize': Tracker must be set!

in my application.rb file I have this at the bottom of it.

```
if Rails.env == "production"
    config.middleware.use("Rack::GoogleAnalytics", :web_property_id => "UA-18760745-1")
    end
```

If O take that out the error goes away so it has something to do with initializing this behavior, but just not quite sure why.

Anyone ran into this issue and have a solution to it, that they could share.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I could find was to not use that Gem and use this one instead as it works right out of the box. Maybe someone else can prove me wrong, which I hope.

Hope this other link helps someone else.

https://github.com/bgarret/google-analytics-rails#readme

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps, but here is my code:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::GoogleAnalytics, :tracker => 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1'
```

in application.rb

I'm assuming it requires a value for the :tracker symbol upon initialization (I'm following this readme on the gem's GitHub: https://github.com/kangguru/rack-google-analytics)

Obviously, replace XXXXXXXXX with your organization's tracker code.

And it seems like setting the :web_property_id symbol is a feature of a different (but similarly named) gem, rack-google_analytics: https://github.com/ambethia/rack-google_analytics