# Lauching openshift rails app - Error "Tracker must be set!"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, openshift

Pardon my lack of knowledge of Rails app deployment, but I am having an error when I push my rails app to openshift, I get an error with Passenger:

`Tracker must be set!`

If you want to the error message, visit: http://beta-happycard.rhcloud.com/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an error on your page anymore but in the future if you see that error check out [rack-google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467369/rack-google-analytics).